# Need help writing a $wpdb query

Tags: wpdb, sql

I am trying to search through post meta for keyword matches but I'm new to MySQL and I don't know how to write my query. I can write a basic query for `post_title` matches but I don't know how to properly jump across tables.

In pseudo code, my query would be

```
"SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
WHERE meta_key LIKE '%$query%' AND post_type = 'project'"
```

My problem is that the `post_type` is only available in the `posts` table and I don't know how to make the connection between `postmeta` and `posts` to check if the `ID` is in fact the correct post type.

Comment: Once you get a list of posts, then filter out the non-wanted post types by unsetting them from the list with `"project" !== get_post_type($post_ID)` condition.. Just a thought. Or a custom WP_Query would help http://pastebin.com/jjEEgwsw

Comment: I need my query to be as efficient as possible since I have hundreds of thousands of records to search through. I can already see a noticeable difference between the speed of using $wpdb and WP_Query when searching for post titles.

Comment: Caching is the key. WP_Query caches requests so you wouldn't worry about the performance and resource usage. Queries made through `$wpdb` methods won't be cached.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'project' ),
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'meta_key',
            'value'     => '%$query%',
        ),
    ),
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but try this one:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '%$query%'
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'project'
```

it worked for me

Comment: After changing the table prefix and the changing `.meta_key` to `.meta_value` this wouldn't work for me but thanks